# Bash script to run command when remote server is available

Tags: bash

I have an application which depends on another remote service. What's I'd like to do is to make simple script which will run command locally when remote server will be available.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

CONNECTED = 0

while [ $CONNECTED != 1 ]; do
    if [ $(ping my-service.com) != null ] then
        my-command.sh
        let CONNECTED = 1
    fi

    sleep 2
done
```

Actually it doesn't work because of ping command. It cause 'Name or service not known' error. I can compare string fully to make it work, but the question is if there are any ready-to-use commands, libs to do the same? Or mb this approach is bad and I should do it in another way.

Comment: `CONNECTED = 0` there is no space when assigning a variable. It should be `CONNECTED=0`. `[ $(ping my-service.com) != null ]` is strange. Why would you expect `ping` program to print `"null"` string? Use smth like `if ping -c1 "$ip_addr" 2>/dev/null >/dev/null` to check if ip_addr is available. The error `Name or service not known` indicates you have no internet connection from your machine at all or that your dns servers are not configured properly. Is this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

CONNECTED=1

while [[ $CONNECTED != 0 ]]; do
    ping -c1 my-service.com 
    CONNECTED=$?
    if [[ $CONNECTED == 0 ]] ; then
        my-command.sh
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```

$? contains the return value of the last executed command (ping in this case). When ping return 0, it means no errors, so it will execute my-command.sh

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to this. I am putting it here if someone needed

```
#!/bin/bash 

until nc -z -v -w60 my-service.com 80
do
  echo "Waiting for connection..."
  sleep 2
done

command.sh
```